# LiveFyre subscription to posts

Tags: web-applications, social-networking, livefyre

I've successfully installed livefyre to a website which lets users post content. I've been searching around if it is possible to subscribe the member to comments which are related to their post ie send an email.

Has anyone done that? Is it possible? How would you go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Livefyre Comment widget has a  follow button that allows anyone with a Livefyre account to get email notifactions about every new comment in that conversation. When someone leaves a comment in a conversation they are also automatically following the conversation.

You could ask your members to click on the follow button for conversations on their own content. This support article has more information about [following a conversation](http://support.livefyre.com/customer/portal/articles/8144-how-do-i-follow-or-unfollow-a-conversation-)